# How to find the exact number of players on a server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-java-edition-server

As players join and leave, I need something(s) giving a redstone signal for every number of players from 1-10, then if there is more than 10. So I can have one thing happen at 1 player, something different happen at 2, 3, 4 ...

I have tried using a comparator output from "/testfor @a", but I couldn't get it to do things like having the command blocks for players=1 and players=2 to turn off if players=3. Everything else I've tried had the same problems, and everything I've found online is for testing for a min/max amount of players.

Comment: Why is this getting downvotes?

Comment: I searched for a while, and I tried "/testfor @a" with a comparator going out, then a line of redstone, but I couldn't get the command blocks before the one for the actual number of players to turn off. Everything else I tried had the same kind of problem.

Comment: You should word that into your question. Include everything you've tried.

Comment: What version of Minecraft is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a scoreboard to hold the value of the amount of players, you can count how many are on with:

```
/execute @a ~ ~ ~ /scoreboard players add <dummy player> <objective> 1
```

then you can use conditional command blocks after a command like this:

```
/scoreboard players test <dummy player> <objective> <min> <max>
```

note: min and max can be set the same for an exact number

but if you want a redstone value of player count, @mookooy gave the answer for that

Answer (score 0):

Have a Repeating, Always Active command block with the command `/testfor @a` and a comparator and no repeater this will produce a signal strength based on the number of players online

Answer (score -1):

Set up some command blocks like this:

**[Repeating, always active] /scoreboard players set @e[name=Counter] players 0**

**[Chain, always active] /execute @a ~ ~ ~ /scoreboard players add @e[name=Counter] players 1**

Create a scoreboard objective named players:

**/scoreboard objectives add players dummy**

Then place some entity in the world and name it "Counter". I'd recommend summoning an invisible armor stand:

**/summon ArmorStand ~ ~ ~ {CustomName:Counter,Invisible:1,Marker:1,NoGravity:1}**

Finally, it really depends on what you need to do. If you REALLY need a redstone output out of it, add these to commands blocks:

**[Chain, always active] /setblock *x y z* air**

**[Chain, always active] /execute @e[name=Counter,score_players_min=10,score_players=10,c=1] ~ ~ ~ /setblock *x y z* redstone_block**

Replace *x y z* with the X Y and Z coordinates of where you want the redstone block to be placed. Press Fn-F3 to open Debug Mode, and then you can see coordinates.

If there 10 players in the world, it will place a block.

Hope this helps!